# Count distinct possible words without rotations or reflections

Tags: combinatorics, necklace-and-bracelets

Suppose I have an alphabet ${\{A, B, C, D\}}$ and I want to count all possible words of length $n$. Easy: it's $4^n$.

What should I do if I want to count all possible words that:

a) are unique given any rotation, and

b) are unique including mirroring

For example:

$AAAA$ would definitely be included part of the total (there are no other strings that are rotations or mirrors of it).

Only one of $BAAA$ or $ABAA$ or $AABA$ or $AAAB$ would count towards the total (as they're all the same under some rotation).

Only one of $ABCD$ or $CDBA$ would count towards the total (as they're mirrors of each other).

Only one of $ABCD$ or $ADCB$ would count towards the total (as you can go between them via a rotation and a mirror).

**A small illustration**

With the above alphabet and words of length 2, there are 10 possible words:

```
AA - counted
AB - counted
AC - counted
AD - counted
BA - not counted (a reversal and also rotation of AB)
BB - counted
BC - counted
BD - counted
CA - not counted (a reversal and also rotation of AC)
CB - not counted (a reversal and also rotation of BC)
CC - counted
CD - counted
DA - not counted (a reversal and also rotation of AD)
DB - not counted (a reversal and also rotation of BD)
DC - not counted (a reversal and also rotation of CD)
DD - counted
```

Comment: Consider the set of ordering of the letter. let $Z/nZ$  act on the set by shifting. We want to count the number of orbit. By Cauchy-Frobinius lemma this is sum of the number of elements fixed by the shifts over n. Then I 'm stuck

Comment: Only 10 words of length 2 as CB == BC. I have not devised a method for counting, but enumeration gives 10, 20, 55 and 136 for lengths 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMathias, fixed my question

Answer (score 1):

After writing [some python](https://pastebin.com/5FJFEi75) to find some numbers by brute force, then searching them on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A051137), I've found out that I'm looking at [Bracelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) numbers, with alphabet size = colours. Which makes sense, since bracelets (AKA turnover necklaces) allow identity under mirroring and rotation.

To summarise the equation I found at OEIS, for $k$ symbols and word length $n$, the count is found by:

$$
T(n, k) = \frac{k^{\lfloor (n+1)/2 \rfloor} + k^{\lceil (n+1)/2 \rceil}} {4} + \frac{ \sum_{d|n} \phi (d) \cdot k^{n/d} } {2n}
$$

I've written a pure python implementation of this equation and it does match my brute force results for all numbers I've tried.

(See also my follow-up question: [Count of bracelets with no adjacent colours the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633494/count-of-bracelets-with-no-adjacent-colours-the-same))