# Arrangements of 3 red beads, 3 green beads, and 3 blue beads if rotations/reflections are the same and no 2 consecutive beads are the same color

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorics-on-words

I've found a problem which gives 3 red beads, 3 green beads, and 3 blue beads. It asks how many arrangements there are of the 3 sets of beads on a necklace, given that the conditions that all 9 beads must be used, no 2 beads that are next to each other can be the same color, and any two arrangements that can be rotated/reflected to match each other are identical.

I'm trying to start by ignoring the 2 consecutive beads cannot be the same color condition, and finding the number of ways to arrange the beads without it. I know that if all 9 beads were distinct, then the answer would just be 9!/9, or 8!. I've tried dividing it by $3!^3$, since there are $3!$ ways to organize each 3 beads of the same color, but that gives a decimal which shouldn't be the answer. I'm not sure how to proceed from here, and then account for the reflections. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at Polya Enumeration theorem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  me contribute  some material  here to  help you  get started  and
initiate additional research.  I must  ask you to consult two previous
posts, however, where essentially 100%  of the answer to your question
is already documented. These are

- [Counting    proper    colorings   of    necklaces    (rotational
  symmetry)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164399/)
- [Counting    proper     colorings    of    bracelets    (dihedral
  symmetry)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633494/)

Using the notation  from the above, for the rotations  we must replace
the  count $P_d(k)$  by a  generating function.   By construction  the
$P_d(k)$ arise for permutations with  $d$ cycles of length $n/d$ which
owing to the  coloring being proper requires a  properly colored cycle
of length $d$ call it $\beta$ with  at most the given number of colors
(the $d$ cycles are adjacent  and monochrome by Burnside).  This cycle
is repeated around the bracelet.  Therefore we have solved the problem
if  we can  construct  a  generating function  by  colors of  properly
colored cycles, where symmetries are  not taken into account.  This is
done recursively using a memoized algorithm that classifies generating
functions  of paths  by the  first and  last color  of the  paths they
represent,  which are  then  used to  build cycles.   Now  if a  color
appears on one of these cycles we must replace its variable $C$ in the
generating function by $C^{n/d}$ because the cycle $\beta$ induces the
colors  of the  $d$ cycles  which make  up the  permutation. With  the
reflections which only  contribute when $n$ is even where  the axis of
reflection  passes  through opposite  vertices  we  need a  generating
function of properly colored paths with no symmetry and we take one of
these to constitute the colors on one  side and induce the ones on the
other.   This  means we  replace  each  variable from  the  generating
function by its  square, compensating for the two  colors which appear
on the  fixed points, which  contribute only once.  This  is basically
all.   Here  is  the  generating function  for  proper  non-isomorphic
colorings of a  nine-bracelet using at most three  colors as requested
by OP:

$${C_{{1}}}^{4}{C_{{2}}}^{4}C_{{3}}+3\,{C_{{1}}}^{4}{C_{{2}
}}^{3}{C_{{3}}}^{2}+3\,{C_{{1}}}^{4}{C_{{2}}}^{2}{C_{{3}}
}^{3}+{C_{{1}}}^{4}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{4}\\+3\,{C_{{1}}}^{3}{
C_{{2}}}^{4}{C_{{3}}}^{2}+8\,{C_{{1}}}^{3}{C_{{3}}}^{3}{C
_{{2}}}^{3}+3\,{C_{{1}}}^{3}{C_{{2}}}^{2}{C_{{3}}}^{4}+3
\,{C_{{1}}}^{2}{C_{{2}}}^{4}{C_{{3}}}^{3}\\+3\,{C_{{1}}}^{2
}{C_{{2}}}^{3}{C_{{3}}}^{4}+C_{{1}}{C_{{2}}}^{4}{C_{{3}}}
^{4}.$$

Therefore the answer to the query is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{8.}$$

Here is an excerpt for the case  of a twelve-bracelet with at most $5$
colors:

$$\ldots +16\,C_{{1}}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{6}
{C_{{4}}}^{2}{C_{{5}}}^{2}+10\,C_{{1}}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{6
}C_{{4}}{C_{{5}}}^{3}+3\,C_{{1}}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{6}{C_{{
5}}}^{4}\\+15\,C_{{1}}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{5}{C_{{4}}}^{5}+153
\,C_{{1}}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{5}{C_{{4}}}^{4}C_{{5}}+408\,C_
{{1}}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{5}{C_{{4}}}^{3}{C_{{5}}}^{2}\\+408\,
C_{{1}}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{5}{C_{{4}}}^{2}{C_{{5}}}^{3}+153
\,C_{{1}}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{5}C_{{4}}{C_{{5}}}^{4}+15\,C_{
{1}}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{5}{C_{{5}}}^{5}\\+3\,C_{{1}}C_{{2}}{C
_{{3}}}^{4}{C_{{4}}}^{6}+153\,C_{{1}}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{4}
{C_{{4}}}^{5}C_{{5}}+1014\,C_{{1}}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{4}{C_
{{4}}}^{4}{C_{{5}}}^{2}\\+1783\,C_{{1}}C_{{2}}{C_{{3}}}^{4}
{C_{{4}}}^{3}{C_{{5}}}^{3}+\ldots$$

The  Maple code  for this  is shown  below. It  includes a  very basic
enumeration routine that  confirmed the results from  Burnside for all
examples that were examined.

```
with(combinat);
with(numtheory);

P := (d,k) -> (k-1)^d + (-1)^d*(k-1);

chr_bracelet_uniq :=
proc(n, k)
local res, d;

    res := 1/2/n*add(phi(n/d)*P(d,k),
                     d in divisors(n));

    if type(n, even) then
        res := res +
        1/4*k*(k-1)^(n/2);
    fi;

    res;
end;

chr_count :=
proc(gf)
local vars, v, sl;

    vars := indets(gf);
    sl := [seq(v=1, v in vars)];
    subs(sl, gf);
end;


chr_gf_rec :=
proc(len, cols, first, last)
option remember;
local c1, c2, res;

    if len = 1 then return 0 fi;
    if len = 2 then
        if first <> last then
            return C[first]*C[last]
        else
            return 0;
        fi;
    fi;

    res := 0;

    if len = 3 then
        for c1 to cols do
            if c1 <> first and c1 <> last then
                res := res +
                C[first]*C[c1]*C[last];
            fi;
        od;

        return res;
    fi;

    for c1 to cols do
        if c1 <> first then
            for c2 to cols do
                if c2 <> last then
                    res := res +
                    C[first]*C[last] *
                    chr_gf_rec(len-2, cols, c1, c2);
                fi;
            od;
        fi;
    od;

    expand(res);
end;

chr_gf_path :=
proc(len, cols)
local c1, c2;
    if len = 1 then
        return add(C[c1], c1=1..cols);
    fi;
    add(add(chr_gf_rec(len, cols, c1, c2),
            c2 = 1..cols), c1=1..cols);
end;

chr_gf_cycle :=
proc(len, cols)
local c1, c2;
    if len=1 then return 0 fi;
    add(add(`if`(c1 <> c2,
                 chr_gf_rec(len, cols, c1, c2), 0),
            c2 = 1..cols), c1=1..cols);
end;

chr_gf_bracelet_uniq :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local res, d, sl, q, c1, c2;

    res := 0;

    for d in divisors(n) minus {1} do
        sl := [seq(C[q] = C[q]^(n/d), q=1..k)];
        res := res +
        phi(n/d)*subs(sl, chr_gf_cycle(d, k))/2/n;
    od;

    if type(n, even) then
        sl := [seq(C[q] = C[q]^2, q=1..k)];

        for c1 to k do
            for c2 to k do
                res := res +
                expand(subs(sl, chr_gf_rec(n/2+1, k, c1, c2))
                       /C[c1]/C[c2]/4);
            od;
        od;
    fi;

    res;
end;

ENUM :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local orbits, rec, col, gf, term;

    orbits := table();

    rec :=
    proc(sofar)
    local orbit, rot, rseq, q, c;

        if nops(sofar) < n then
            for c to k do
                if sofar[-1] <> c then
                    rec([op(sofar), c]);
                fi;
            od;
            return;
        fi;

        if sofar[1] = sofar[-1] then
            return;
        fi;

        orbit := [];

        for rot from 0 to n-1 do
            rseq :=
            [seq(sofar[1+((q+rot) mod n)],
                 q=0..n-1)];
            orbit := [op(orbit), rseq];

            rseq :=
            [seq(rseq[n+1-q], q=1..n)];
            orbit := [op(orbit), rseq];
        end;

        orbits[sort(orbit)[1]] := 1;
    end;

    for col to k do rec([col]) od;

    gf := 0;

    for term in [indices(orbits, 'nolist')] do
        gf := gf +
        mul(C[col], col in term);
    od;

    gf;
end;
```